# Is variable naming possible for critical directive in openmp?

Tags: openmp, critical-section

I want run the following loop for counting elements in parallel.
Since `count[j]` is only updated by iterations where `(X[i] / exp) % 10` evaluates to `j` I want to define a different critical section for each of these. I first thought of using reduction clause on each of the array elements but that gave a compilation error. I know this code is wrong but how should I implement this sort of thing?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        #pragma omp critical((X[i] / exp) % 10)
        count[(X[i] / exp) % 10]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this where there is a single update, the normal solution is to use an atomic.

```
#pragma omp atomic
count[(X[i] / exp) % 10]++;
```

Alternatively you can use OpenMP reduction on the whole array, see Example reduction.7.c on page 238 of [OpenMP 4.5 Examples](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf)